# Break the word at specific letter in mobile view email html

Tags: html, css, ampscript

I have an email `aaa@aa.com` (the real one is really long). In desktop view, it comes out fine but in mobile view I want it to render as `aaa@` in one line and aa.com in another line if the whole email does not fit in the same line.

I am trying to create an email in the marketing cloud using ampscript.

> word-wrap: break-word does not work because it is breaking the email
>   at random place whereas I want to break it specifically after '@'

Comment: For something like that you would probably have to use javascript... but you can't use javascript in an html email

Comment: Why don't break the email at a certain length server-side since you are using ampscript ?

Comment: I need to use it in both mobile and desktop versions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`<wbr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) tag just after 'aaa@' to have it break there whenever possible.

[image: A screenshot of two emails one with the wbr tag and one without. The one with the wbr tag breaks at the desired place.]
*Screenshot from outlook.com*

Note that not all email clients (most notably gmail) support this tag: https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-wbr/

Comment: I used it the following way
<span style="color: #167cac!important;">aaa@<wbr>aa.com</span>
aaa is coming in one color and aa.com is coming in another color. Not sure why that is happening.

Comment: @sujithK I can't reproduce the different colors in any major browser, what environment are you working in?